# Why calc() shows errors in css file

Tags: css

Working on calc css function its work properly in browser and less file. But my text-editor shows error within css file.

[This is the css file (I use VS  code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERvke.png)

Comment: And what is your question? Could you at least share the full and exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't define `$gutter-horizontal` anywhere, so its value cannot be used in the calculation. You need to initialise this variable with something like:

```
$gutter-horizontal: '12px';
```

Note that `calc()` will not work correctly with Sass, and to accommodate for this, you'll need to interpolate the variable:

```
width: calc((100% - #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 2)
```

Also, the vast majority of your CSS won't compile as you have pre-processed SASS in a `.css` file. You can convert it to regular CSS using an online tool such as **[SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/)** (or simply change the file extension to `.scss`, assuming your project can compile SASS).

Answer (score 0):

your file is a css, your syntax it's for some preprocessor like sass or less